# Would [affirmative-action] be a useful tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Would it be useful to have an [affirmative-action](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/affirmative-action) tag for [discrimination](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discrimination) questions that are specifically about actions intended to benefit underrepresented groups?

This could be a useful differentiation because it is often argued that there is a fundamental difference between discrimination against underrepresented groups and discrimination in their favor. For example, in the United States, virtually everyone agrees that it is illegal for colleges to favor white people in their acceptance processes, it took [a Supreme Court ruling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Students_for_Fair_Admissions_v._Harvard) to settle the issue of whether or not they could favor people of color (and this case overturned [prior precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regents_of_the_University_of_California_v._Bakke) that such policies are permissible).

Comment: please explain why the tag might be more useful than just having discrimination.

Comment: @Trish I added a paragraph to the question.

Comment: This tag would've been helpful for this question of mine: https://law.stackexchange.com/q/93764/10132